# Сохранение графика из Chartа в Delphi

Tags: delphi

Всем здравствуйте. Прошу помочь мне. Проблема следующая: в Charte нарисовала графики (в общем серий 20 где-то получилось), нужно было сделать кое-какие надписи на графиках -использовала Label'ы. Рисунок сохраняла с помощью SavePictureDialog. Но сохраняются только сами графики, label'ы - увы - нет. Нет ли какого-нибудь способа, чтоб вместе сохранить и графики и подписи на них? Заранее спасибо. ))

Answer (score 1):

Есть такой способ. Класс Tchart содержит в себе канву для рисования. Для вывода текста над графиками нужно использовать её, а не лэйблы.
`...
Chart1:Tchart;
...
Chart1.Canvas.Textout(X,Y,TEXT); 
...`
Тогда надписи будут "нарисованными", а не "наложенными" поверх.

Для вывода можно использовать так же TLineseries с его сабклассом TMarks.

Comment: Спасибо, Bushfighter. Так я пробовала делать, но почему-то надписей не видно,если есть графики, нарисованные с помощью Series1.AddXY().
Думала, может я ошибочно пишу,создала новый чарт и только надпись попробовала вывести - все работает. Теперь вот решила все графики на Canvase перерисовывать. НАдеюсь, что с сохранением на Canvase проблем не возникнет....

Comment: Не возникнет точно. Так я делал, способ проверенный, но долгий.

Comment: Пробовала и 'до' и 'после' - ничего не получается. Даже если бы и получилось, понятия не имею как сохранять вместе Canvas Charta  и сам Chart.. Спасибо за отклик, пойду покорять Canvas)))

Comment: Ну попробуйте еще GDI+. Хотя для вашей задачи разницы не будет. А так полезно освоить)  
А вообще[TLinesSeries](http://www.berneda.com/TeeChart6Docs/TLineSeries.html) можно и без канвы обойтись, все есть )

Comment: А как там выводить на графике надписи типа "R=20" возле нарисованной окружности?

Comment: [TMarks]http://www.berneda.com/TeeChart6Docs/TChartSeries.Marks.html